# error In sub query in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, dql

**subquery** and **querybuilder** in my project but result is error

my dql code is

```
  $subQb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery = $subQb->select('COUNT(v.id)')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Visitsite', 'v')
                ->where('v.site = s.id')
                ->Andwhere('v.createdate > :date')
                ->getDQL();

            $subQb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery2 = $subQb2->select('l.quantity')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Limitviewday', 'l')
                ->where($subQb2->expr()->eq('s.limitviewday', 'l.id'))
                ->getDQL();


            $subQb3 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery3 = $subQb3->select('COUNT(i.id)')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Visitsite', 'i')
                ->where('i.site = s.id')
                ->Andwhere('i.createdate > :date2')
                ->Andwhere('i.ip = :ip')
                ->groupBy('i.ip')
                ->getDQL();

            $subQb4 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery4 = $subQb4->select('ipl.quantity')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Iplimitview', 'ipl')
                ->where('s.iplimitview = ipl.id')
                ->getDQL();


            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $query = $qb->select('s')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Sites', 's')
                ->where('s.quantity > :one')
                ->Andwhere('s.status = :two')
                ->Andwhere($qb->expr()->lt("($subquery)", "($subquery2)"))
                ->Andwhere($qb->expr()->lt("(COALESCE(  ($subquery3),0) )", "($subquery4))"))
                ->setParameter('one', 1)
                ->setParameter('two', 1)
                ->setParameter('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
                ->setParameter('ip', $ip)
                ->setParameter('date2', $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));


            $settlements = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

and my result dql is

```
SELECT s FROM AdminBundle:Sites s WHERE s.quantity > :one AND s.status = :two AND ((SELECT COUNT(v.id) FROM AdminBundle:Visitsite v WHERE v.site = s.id AND v.createdate > :date) < (SELECT l.quantity FROM AdminBundle:Limitviewday l WHERE s.limitviewday = l.id)) AND ((COALESCE( (SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM AdminBundle:Visitsite i WHERE i.site = s.id AND i.createdate > :date2 AND i.ip = :ip GROUP BY i.ip),0) ) < (SELECT ipl.quantity FROM AdminBundle:Iplimitview ipl WHERE s.iplimitview = ipl.id)))
```

every ting is ok but my result is error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 279: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'

Answer (score 0):

Your output sql is `SELECT s FROM AdminBundle:Sites` but it is wrong.

correction is

```
SELECT *FROM AdminBundle:Sites
```

`s` is not field, should be use before `FROM` column name like `s.quantity, s.stauts` like that

Please edit your code in this like : `$query = $qb->select('s')` change select `'s'` link above instruction

Comment: my problem is ``` ->Andwhere($qb->expr()->lt("(COALESCE(  ($subquery3),0) )", "($subquery4))"))``` select from sites is ok

Comment: firstly you can correction `$query = $qb->select('s')`. because `s` is not column name, this is most error. let me know

Comment: You getting `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 279: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'` this error. right?

Comment: I thinks you know this is `Syntax Error`. That's means some wrong is sql query. Please can you correction in this line `$query = $qb->select('s')`. if you use select `s`. you are getting all time `Syntex error` because `s` is not column name. Before `FROM` after `SELECT` must be used table column name. I hope you understand

Comment: no, when remove line ``` ->Andwhere($qb->expr()->lt("(COALESCE(  ($subquery3),0) )", "($subquery4))"))```query and code is ok and running so subquery3 is corrupted